# Is there a way of creation sessions in django via class based views after posting data?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, django-sessions

```
class CreateCompanyView(CreateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'create/company_create.html'
    form_class = CompanyForm
    success_url = '/'

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = self.form_class(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            instance = form.save(commit=False)
            #section where the session is supposed to be created
            request.session['company'] =instance.pk
            instance.save()
        return redirect("/")
```

I would appreciate if someone has a simpler way or another alternative based on using class based views

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Class based views that process forms have a method `form_valid` which is run in case the form is valid. Since you want to write some extra code for that specific case, you should override that method instead of `post`:

```
class CreateCompanyView(CreateView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'create/company_create.html'
    form_class = CompanyForm
    success_url = '/'
    
    def form_valid(self, form):
        response = super().form_valid(form)
        self.request.session['company'] = self.object.pk # `form_valid` saves the object to the variable `self.object`
        return response
```